# show a block of pixel from greyimage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a grey image and i want to get the pixel value from every 8 pixel together
  (block   of pixel)
  How can i read this block of pixel  from a grey image ?
  This the code i have make

```
void main()

{
 Mat img = imread("Frame.jpg",0);

if(!img.data)   
    std::cout << "error";

double minVal, maxVal;
minMaxLoc(img,&minVal,&maxVal,NULL,NULL);
double Threshold = 0.5 * (minVal + maxVal);
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<img.rows;i++)
    for(j=0;j<img.cols;j++)
        unsigned char Pixel = img.at<unsigned char>(i,j);




namedWindow( "Display window", CV_NORMAL );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", img );
 waitKey(0);    

     }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unsure exactly what you are trying to do, but, if you are trying to get the pixels surrounding the center pixel, you could manually do it by adjusting your index. If the block around the pixel is labeled as such:

```
0 1 2
3 P 4
5 6 7
```

You could get the values for 0-7 by doing this in your loop

```
for (i=1;i<img.rows-1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<img.cols-1;j++){
        unsigned char Pixel = img.at<unsigned char>(i,j);
        unsigned char Pixel_0 = img.at<unsigned char>(i-1,j-1);
        unsigned char Pixel_1 = img.at<unsigned char>(i,j-1);
        unsigned char Pixel_2 = img.at<unsigned char>(i+1,j-1);
        unsigned char Pixel_3 = img.at<unsigned char>(i-1,j);
        unsigned char Pixel_4 = img.at<unsigned char>(i+1,j);
        unsigned char Pixel_5 = img.at<unsigned char>(i-1,j+1);
        unsigned char Pixel_6 = img.at<unsigned char>(i,j+1);
        unsigned char Pixel_7 = img.at<unsigned char>(i+1,j+1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to subset the whole window into a new cv::Mat you could use an ROI.

```
for (i=1;i<img.rows-1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<img.cols-1;j++){
        unsigned char Pixel = img.at<unsigned char>(i,j);
        cv::Mat ROI = img(cv::Rect(i-1,j-1,3,3));
    }
}
```

Note for both cases the loop is only between 1->rows-1 and 1->cols-1, You'd have to handle the boundary cases separately.

Comment: Thanks david for your answer i have made another code who can read from every row 16*16 pixel array,now i need to get the pixel value from every array,because im searching for a code in the picture who have the succesive color black,and then white and then ,black and white ,if you wnat i can share my code and the picture perhaps u have idea how i can do this